# std::deque - доступ к элементу

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот у std::deque есть метод ".at" - который предоставляет доступ к элементу.

Есть ли разница между "at" и доступом через итератор ?

Вот для примера:

```
std::deque<int>::iterator deq_iterator = my_deq.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < my_deq.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << *deq_iterator << std::endl;
    
        deq_iterator++;
    }
```

...

```
for (int i = 0; i < my_deq.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << my_deq.at(i) << std::endl;
}
```

То в первом случае проход по цикле по элементам будет скажем так эффективным, то есть для доступа к последующему i-элементу - будет начинается с предыдущего итератора, который увеличивается на один каждую итерацию цикла, а не каждый раз с нулевого элемента очереди.

А вот будет также это делаться при использовании метода "at" или же в этом случае каждый раз доступ к i-му элюенту будет искаться с нулевого элемента очереди ?

Comment: скорее всего доступ по итератору будет чуточку быстрее, как минимум, потому что индекс быстрее искать, итератор не требудет проверки индекса, а at будет проверять выход за границы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, что токае итератор? в большинстве случаев это просто указатель с небольшой обвязкой или индекс(ы). Все. Поэтому, если у нас есть итератор на элемент, то нужно просто сделать разыменование (и в большинстве случаев сам указатель на элемент у нас уже есть либо вычисляется элементарно). Поэтому, можно считать, что в большинстве случаев, получение элемента по итератору происходит за константное время.

Есть особые случаи, например, доступ по итератору к содержимому файла или если у нас "вычисляемый контейнер" (иногда бывает удобно не хранить все элементы, а просто вычислять по мере надобности, например, "вектор простых чисел"), но это отдельная тема и к этому не имеет отношения.

Теперь перейдем к функции at, которая есть в многих контейнеров. Согласно стандарту, она должна сделать проверки на выход за пределы контейнера и если что то пошло не так - сгенерировать исключение. А потом, если все проверки пройшли, то может просто обратится к `operator[]`, который не обязан делать проверок выхода за пределы (хотя в дебажных сборках проекта студия может и добавить таких проверок, что бы поймать возможные проблемы на подлете:)).

То есть, обычно at содержит условие + возможное исключение и вычисление положения элемента. Есть много компаний, где считают, что даже возможность сгенерировать исключение даст падение производительности на пару процентов, что приведет к потере миллионов.

Если почитать документацию на deque, то там сказано, что обращение к элементу это обычно два разыменования.

> typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays, with additional bookkeeping, which means indexed access to deque must perform two pointer dereferences, compared to vector's indexed access which performs only one.

Переводя на простой язык, можно считать, что deque это вектор или список векторов, и что бы получить элемент по индексу, нужно либо для каждого массивчика хранить индекс начала и как минимум его найти (а это в лучшем случае бинарный поиск), но при этом при каждом добавлении/удалении нужно будет индексы обновлять, либо просто хранить размер, но тогда нужно будет вначале линейно пробежаться по массиву верхнего уровня, что бы найти тот элемент, который хранит подходящий внутренний. В любом случае это не очень быстро. А вот с итераторами тут просто - храним два числа и готово. Нужно пойти вперед (сделать ++) - увеличили один счетчик, проверили, если вышли за пределы, увеличили второй счетчик, а первый в ноль.

Но будет ли это действительно быстрее и насколько? надо бенчмаркать и смотреть.  Возможно, в Вашем случае все будет наоборот.

Вывод - скорее всего, для deque самым быстрым будет итератор, потом operator[] и в самом конце at.

Comment: простенький бенчмарк на коленке просто в цикле показал, что итератор-через "сделать++" и просто .at - отличаются по скорости в два раза, в пользу итератора конечно.